# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity java.lang.NullPointerException 02-21 22:55:01.480: E/And

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I want to make maps and show all markers or locations in google maps. I have created a class database for latitude and longitude. I call latitude and longitude for view location in google maps. I've this code

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Database_Puskesmas.class);

        msg_latitude = intent.getStringExtra("dataLatitude");
        msg_longitude = intent.getStringExtra("dataLogitude");

        double la = Double.parseDouble(msg_latitude);
        double lo = Double.parseDouble(msg_longitude);

        //Database_Puskesmas db = new Database_Puskesmas(this);

         LatLng latLng = new LatLng(la, lo);

        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    }
```

But when I run the program, I get the following error:

```
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.application.bpjs/com.application.bpjs.PetaPuskesmas_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:244)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at com.application.bpjs.PetaPuskesmas_Activity.onLocationChanged(PetaPuskesmas_Activity.java:491)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at com.application.bpjs.PetaPuskesmas_Activity.onCreate(PetaPuskesmas_Activity.java:151)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
02-21 22:55:01.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     ... 11 more
02-21 22:55:10.409: I/Process(4072): Sending signal. PID: 4072 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Database_Puskesmas.class);
    msg_latitude = intent.getStringExtra("dataLatitude");
    msg_longitude = intent.getStringExtra("dataLogitude");
```

Just preparing intent without adding `dataLatitude` and `dataLogitude` key and tying to get both keys from Intent.

Use `onLocationChanged` method `location` parameter for getting `Latitude` and `Logitude` like:

```
double la = location.getLatitude();
double lo = location.getLongitude();
```

Comment: for location.getlatiude(); that's just to show marker my location not for show all location in database, i'm confused how to call all location in database for make a marker. not one marker but all marker, if my databas have 10 database, then show all 10 marker in my maps

Comment: @yunikhoirunnisa: then get all coordinates from db and show in map. what is issue?

Comment: the problem is forseclose when i click button show map all location. but i make that's code to comments that's running. so how? how i show all coordinates in DB

Comment: @yunikhoirunnisa: first read all coordinates from db then show in map.show your code where reading from db

Comment: it's like this 'Inten intent = getInten();' 'double la = Double.parseDouble(msg_latitude); '??

Comment: Would you please help here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649349/cannot-cancel-alarm-once-its-rang